# SAP B1 AddOn, What is the best place to check if table exist and create table?

Tags: c#, add-on, sapb1

I'm creating an add-on to SAP B1 and I need know what is the best place to create my addon tables on database?

For next versions I need check and update the table columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use the SAP UserTables, it is what SAP recommends, you can create them in the SAP Application Tools --> Customization Tools --> User-Defined Tables - Setup

If you want do it coding you have to use the UserTablesMD object. You can find more information about add-ons in the SAP official forum 
http://scn.sap.com/community/business-one-sdk

If you want to check if the table exists you can either use the same object by the GeyByKey method, or using the Recordset querying the OUTB table.

Comment: Hi, thanks man. But, where layer of my add-on I use UserTablesMD and I need know if table exists or not.

Comment: The layer, if I understood it is up to you but I usually put this right after connecting to SAP.

Comment: Hi @Teta, yes you understood! It that i need, but I need check everytime the client open SAP? Exist a manner to check the tables it just on import the add-on?

Comment: well, if you customize your add-on installer it might be possible, but I think it is a too big effort. I have seen add-ons where you have a program that will be in charge of creating all the database structure, tables, fields, etc and the add-on itself. 
Another option is also creating a table or maybe a file in the server to keep your data about the add-ons updates, then instead of checking all tables you can check the information like the add-on version that you have in your "auxiliar" table/file.

Comment: Thanks @Teta. I develop this database check after the connection to SAP, then I post the code here to help others...

Answer (score 1):

Developed a framework that controls the creation of tables and fields within the addon, also maps events and makes treatment exception among other things.
This framework is still under development and is already in use in many addons.

Below are example of how to create the tables and fields using the framework

UserTable

```
[Tables(nome: "SZACONFIG", descricao: "Configurações plugins", tipo: BoUTBTableType.bott_NoObject, tabelaSistema: false)]
public class Configuracoes : TableBase
{
    [Fields("NomeUsu", "Nome de Usuário", 150, true, BoFldSubTypes.st_None)]
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }

    [Fields("NomePlg", "Nome do Plugin", 200, true, BoFldSubTypes.st_None)]
    public string NomePlugin { get; set; }

    [Fields("Ativo", "Ativo", 1, false, BoFldSubTypes.st_None)]
    [ValoresValidos("N", "Não")]
    [ValoresValidos("Y", "Sim")]
    public string Ativo { get; set; }



}
```

Table System

```
[Tables("OUSR", "Cadastro de Usuários", true)]
    public class OUSR : TableBase
    {


        [Fields("AdmPlg", "Administrar Plugin", 1, "N", false, BoFldSubTypes.st_None)]
        [ValoresValidos( "N", "Não")]
        [ValoresValidos( "S", "Sim")]
        public string AdmPlg { get; set; }




    }
```

If you are interested I can provide

Comment: Vou compilar e montar um exemplo para voce. Creio que vai facilitar.